# Not able to login with both server and windows authentication on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, windows

Getting error with both windows and server authentication while logging In to SQL 2012.
I googled that but was not able to find any proper solution which sorted out my problem.

Thank you,

Comment: are you trying to connect to localhost ?or are you trying to connect to a server machine ?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 65536

Answer (score 0):

Restart SQLSERVER services from services.msc and then it will work.

Comment: you have created a user for SQL Server but you can't login using the credentials, is that the problem?

Comment: I have multiple Users, I can't login with any of them, both windows and server authentication.

Comment: Have you created both the login (with password) and database user for the same login?

Comment: I was able to login with server authentication but was facing an issue with Windows authentication. With restart of Server now, i'm not able with both.